# I want to Hide different languages from google translate API

Tags: javascript, html, google-translation-api

Hi there I am using google translate API for translation on my web page.
I want to remove some of the languages And want to show some of the languages
how to do it? How can I access the select dropdown of google translate api?

```
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

This is the code I am using.
And when I translate I get the odd navbar on the Top can somehow I remove it?

Comment: Try to use: includedLanguages ```google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'bn,en,kn' , layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element');```

Comment: can you make send me this in proper code format?